# React How to pass field date from datepicker as Api url parameter

Tags: arrays, reactjs, datepicker, fetch

I am fetching data from an API that has a date as a parameter
this date comes from the material picker of react the format for date should be yyyy-MM-dd, but when I select a date with my datepicker it passes date as

> Tue Oct 12 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
> I want the date sent by datpiecker to be as my required format: `yyyy-MM-dd`
> this is a prt of my code :
>
> ```
> import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
> import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
> import {DatePicker, KeyboardDatePicker,MuiPickersUtilsProvider,} from "@material-ui/pickers";
>
> function ExchangeRate() {
>   
>
>     const [date, setDate] = useState(moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
>    
>
>     useEffect(() => {
>    
>   
>     function getExchangeRates(base, currencyCode) {
>        
>         const url = `https://data.fixer.io/api/${date}?&base=USD`;
>
>         
>         return fetch(url)
>             .then((res) => res.json())
>             .then(handleAPIErrors)
>             .then((res) => res.rates);
> return (
>           
>           
>                     </CSelect>
>                
>               
>
>
>                   
>           <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
>     
>             <KeyboardDatePicker
>             autoOk
>               label="Material Date Picker"
>               format="yyyy-MM-dd"
>               animateYearScrolling
>               value={date}
>               onChange={date => setDate(date)}
>             />
>             
>           </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format your date using `moment` when using the in the api URL as follow:

```
const url = `https://data.fixer.io/api/${moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD")}?&base=USD`;
```

Or if you want to consistently store the date with that format in the state, you can change the `onChange` event as follow:

```
onChange={date => setDate(moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD"))}
```

In the `KeyboardDatePicker` component the `format` prop only defines how the date is displayed in that component, and not how it is used in the `onChange` event.

Comment: Thank you Houssam, your solution works perfectly  for the onChange i want the API to be fetched everytime i change the date, as useCallback, how to do that ?

Comment: You can achieve this by wrapping the code you want to execute when the `date` state variable change in a `useEffect` hook and passing as a second parameter (the dependency array) the following: `[date]`. This would result in `useEffect(() => { ... }, [date]);`. As a result, the effect will be executed on each change of that variable.

Comment: You can refer to the documentation about this: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects